# Step few instruction with GDB

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

`si` is step 1 instruction , How can I move few steps with 1 GDB commands?

For example I want to skip 3 instruction after address 0xabcd

```
b *0xabcd
---Breakpoint 2 at xabcd
commands 2
si
si
si
end
```

But this skip only 1 instruction , not 3

Comment: What's the output of gdb when the breakpoint is reached?

Comment: @ssbssa The output is like only single step run

Comment: I can reproduce this on my end. Instead you could use the variant with step count, like `si 3`.